# string not working but console works

Tags: c#, .net, string

This might be the stupidest question ever but why this doesn't work,

```
string abc = (" my string = {0}  Your String = {1} " , myS, yourS);
```

when it works like this,

```
Console.WriteLine(" my string = {0}  Your String = {1} " , myS, yourS);
```

Comment: Use string.Format(...)

Comment: "doesn't work" is not enough.U got error or ????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `Console.WriteLine` internally does something like this:

```
string abc = string.Format(" my string = {0}  Your String = {1} " , myS, yourS);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine` internally uses [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) i.e. [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign strings like that.  You can use `Join`. Or `.Format` which will replace `{0}` and `{1}` with their respective values which is what `.WriteLine` does for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `string.Format`. You can't expect the BCL to just understand what `{0}` and `{1}` mean..

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` is a *method* which takes in multiple parameters. This is why you can have such a syntax but when you're assigning a variable, like you are in your first example, you can't pass in parameters in the same way. As mentioned in the other answers, `Console.WriteLine` uses the `String.Format` method.